# Using microtype letterspacing with LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012062812

Tags: luatex, microtype, letterspacing

Does the letterspacing (and tracking) options of microtype not work with the latest version of LuaTeX?

When I try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\fontspec[SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineCapitalsO},
          SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[tracking,letterspace=500]{microtype}
\begin{document}\parindent0em

stealing sheap

\textsc{Stealing Sheep}

\textls[800]{\scshape Stealing Sheep}

\end{document}
```

I get error messages in my .log:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012062812 (TeX Live 2012) (format=lualatex 2012.7.13)  10 AUG 2012 09:14
.....
! Package microtype Error: The `tracking' feature doesn't currently work
(microtype)                with luatex.
......
! Package microtype Error: Letterspacing currently doesn't work with luatex.

See the microtype package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 \textls[800]{\scshape Stealing Sheep}

Run pdftex, or use the `soul' package instead.
```

Comment: I believe that when a warning "Letterspacing currently doesn't work with luatex" appears, it is true. I'm afraid there is nothing to answer here: it is a bug and the package maintainers clearly know about it. Even if they didn't, is was agreed that bug reports does not belong to TeX.SX.

Comment: Kerning is not yet enabled for the latest version of microtype (version 2.5) and luatex (version >=0.62). However, tracking *should* work if you use version 2.5 of `microtype`; this is one of the significant changes over version 2.4. However, version 2.5 is still in late-beta ('beta08' as of May 2012) and must be downloaded and installed by hand. You may obtain it from, e.g., http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=608.

Comment: tohecz: I took this example from a fairly recent TeX & friends posting where it appeared to work with LuaTeX, so I wanted to make sure it wasn't something funny about my setup that triggering this. I in no way indicated this as a "bug report".

Mico: Thanks!

In general: is there another way to handle letterspacing in LuaTeX?

Comment: @BeSlayed: Letterspacing and tracking should both work if you use version 2.5 of the `microtype` package and a version of lua(la)tex more recent than 0.62.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use version 2.5 of the `microtype` package -- still in "late beta", but available online at http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=608 -- you can use the letterspacing and tracking features of the package -- but not (yet) the kerning features; the latter are available only if the package is used with pdflatex.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\fontspec[SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineCapitalsO},
          SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[tracking,letterspace=500]{microtype}
\begin{document}    
stealing sheap

\textsc{Stealing Sheep}

\textls[800]{\scshape Stealing Sheep}
\end{document}
```

[image]